# Material-ui AppBar and Tab at the right edge of the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui

This is what it looks like and I wanted the Links for "Homepage Login Settings and etc.." to be situated at the right edge of the AppBar. This is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I put the tab at the right edge of the screen, but I still want the "Website" to be situated at the left edge of the screen?

Below are the codes:

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };


  //Breakpoints
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar
        style={{
          position: "sticky",
          top: "0",
        }}
      >
        {/*  */}
        <Toolbar
          variant="dense"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
          }}
        >
 
          {isMatch ? (
            <></>
          ) : (
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
              Website
             
            </Typography>
          )}
       

       
          {isMatch ? (
            <h1>
              <div>
                <DrawerComponent />
              </div>
            </h1>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid>
                <Tabs
                  value={value}
                  indicatorColor="primary"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  aria-label="simple tabs example"
                  variant="fullWidth"
                >
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Homepage" to="/" component={Link} />
                  <Tab
                    disableRipple
                    label="Login"
                    to="/login"
                    component={Link}
                  />
               
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Settings" />
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Sample1" />
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Sample2" />
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Sample3" />
                </Tabs>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the css property `flex-grow: 1` to your Title, like this:

```
<Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" style={{flexGrow: 1}}>
```

This is also what Material-ui used to place elements like search bars at the right in [the AppBar examples here](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-search-field).